# Output buffering not working or making any sense

Tags: php, ob-start

I am absolutely stumped here. I must either be missing something very simple or dont understand how this works.

Output buffering does not work at all on MAMP PRO, all contents are simply being displayed on the page and nothing goes to the buffer, not even hello world. I have tried every example

I am creating a simple framework and output buffering just does not work.

I have a module class with a function that includes a file and the code simply shows on the page without me even clearing the buffer.

I have checked the php.ini file in both loaded configuration file and the configuration file shows output_buffering = 4096.
I am so confused

Here is the code example:

```
//index.php
var_dump(ob_start());//returns true
echo "Hello World"; //prints straight to the screen
include MODULES.'/home.php'; //output comes straight out
var_dump(ob_get_contents());//Shows html string
$test = ob_get_contents();
echo $test; //Output gets displayed twice
```

In PHP.ini:
    output_buffering=4096;

Comment: What happens when you begin the file with `<?php` ??

Comment: It just works as normal, as if I never had ob_start(). The function returns true but takes no effect

Comment: So I guess the more important question is, why are you messing with the output buffer anyway? I must have written a few hundred thousand lines of PHP code and haven't needed to mess with that more than twice. About the only time it's important is if you need to send something like a PDF file to the client browser. It is normally handle automatically in the system -- quite a few PHP programmers haven't even heard of `ob_get_contents()` etc,. since they don't need it.

Comment: I am trying to make a modular framework. I dont really want to use it. I was reading articles which suggest that it improves performance so Im trying to make my application as performant as possible. I am quiet happy with including a few files with my html in functions

Comment: Stop trying to improve performance. Get it working first, and improve performance if (and only if) it proves to need improving.

Comment: That makes sense, I will take it on board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ob_get_contents` does not clear the buffer so when a script ends it is flushed to the output as usual. 
If you only want to get data as string and clear buffer use `ob_get_clean()`

You can think of output buffering as creating "bookmarks" or "restore points" in output buffer. For example:

- buffer is empty
- `echo 'hello'` - output buffer has "hello" string
- `ob_start()` - "bookmark" is created
- `echo 'world'` - output buffer has two lines "hello" and "world" strings
- `ob_get_contents()` - returns output buffer content since last "bookmark" - returns "world", but buffer contents stay the same
- scripts ends and flushes whole output buffer to screen
- if you use `ob_get_clean()` instead it returns contents since last "bookmark" and deletes it from output buffer - the buffer has only "hello" in it

EDIT: I know it's very simple and naive explanation but I recall it helped me a lot to grasp the concept.

Comment: I did that, The point is, the buffer simply does not work from the start, which I find strange. So is it normal that the hello world prints to the screen? I thought if I use ob_start() nothing below should print to the screen? Thats at least what the examples say?

Comment: @PM7Temp I edited some detailed explanation. Hope it clarifies things.

Comment: @PM7Temp `ob_start` does not prevent output. It just delays sending data until the end of script (or when buffer is flushed).

Comment: Oh okay, so If my module functions are returning included files, then I guess there is no point to this as the included file will spit everything on the page anyway.

Comment: I would like to use ob_start to get all my html as one string and then manipulate it, but I cant because it does not evaluate php loops, functions inside it

Comment: Replace `ob_get_contents` with `ob_get_clean` and see what happens. Maybe that's what you need. I'm getting confused here, because either I didn't understand your question or you didn't read and understood my answer :)

Comment: Your answer makes sense, I clearly dont understand how to do this properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201912/discussion-between-kaczmen-and-pm7temp).

Comment: When I just do ob_get_clean nothing shows on the screen